# Track by specific fields in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In an Angularjs/Ionic project I have a search input. When I search for something e.g 'search' a get request is made to an internal api and it returns an array of objects. In the same time the search resutls are filtered based on the search. The problem is that I want to get results only when the property firstName matches with 'search' (or it is included) and NOT when an other property e.g. address includes 'search'. This is what is happening now.

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HoiJ.jpg)

[image]

E.g GENOLLI ILIR appears because it includes 'ta' in their address property and NOT in their firstName [an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lTae.jpg)

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-repeat="pat in patients | filter:{firstName:search.name}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution worked for me! I want to add a filter for lastName also. I do it in the same way like that : `<a ng-click="select_patient(pat)" ng-repeat="pat in patients | filter:{firstName: search.name, lastName: search.name}  
                track by $index" class="item item-thumbnail-left imglist_mainmsg_noimg">
                  <h2> {{pat.lastName}} {{pat.firstName}}</h2>
                  <p>   {{pat.amka}}   </p>
                </a>` but it doesn't seem to work properly. Is it a syntax error? I would appreciate your thoughts. :)

Comment: that acts like a 'AND' condition, right?. I think you wish to implement 'OR' condition.
this may work. 
ng-repeat="pat in patients | filter: customFilter"

...and in controller: 

$scope.customFilter = function (item) { 
    return (item.firstName === $scope.search.name) || (item.lastName === $scope.search.name); 
};